# Could not find an 'Invoke' or 'InvokeAsync' method for the view component 'Shoes.Components.CartViewComponent'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I working on the View Component in ASP Net Core MVC. Here my view components

```
 public CartViewComponent(GiaydepContext context)
 {
     _context = context;
 }
 public IViewComponentResult Ivoke()
 {
     if (Total() == 0) 
     {
         ViewBag.Total = 0;
         ViewBag.Totalmoney = 0;
         return View();
     }
  
     ViewBag.Total = Total();
     ViewBag.Totalmoney = TotalMoney();
     return View();
 }
```

[image: Here is the path to Razor View]

I dont know why the error said could not find 'Invoke' or 'InvokeAsync' and the website show the problem is from HomeLayout which where i put MenuViewComponent

Here my MenuViewComponent

```
 public class MenuViewComponent : ViewComponent
 {
     private readonly GiaydepContext _context;
     public MenuViewComponent (GiaydepContext context)
     {
         _context = context;
     }
     public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
     {
         var lstSP = _context.SanPhams
            .Include(n => n.ManhaccNavigation)
            .Include(n => n.MaloaispNavigation);
         return View(lstSP);
     }
 }
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/oftjp.jpg)
[image: Here where I put the Menuviewcompoent]
[image: And the error]

Can you guys know the problems?
I really need help.
Thanks

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Besides "ivoke" seems all good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> public CartViewComponent(GiaydepContext context)  
> {
>     _context = context;
> }
> public IViewComponentResult Ivoke()
> {
>     if (Total() == 0) 
>     {
> ```

Your `CartViewComponent` has an `Ivoke` method, not an `Invoke` method.